# Reading from socket input stream returns data in the wrong order

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I am sending byte arrays over a socket. The sent data starts off with 4 bytes indicating the length of the following byte array.

```
// get the amount of data being sent
byte[] lengthOfReplyAsArray = new byte[4];
forceRead(inputStream, lengthOfReplyAsArray);
int lengthOfReply = byteArrayToInt(lengthOfReplyAsArray);

// read the data into a byte array
byte[] reply = new byte[lengthOfReply];
forceRead(inputStream, reply);
```

The method used to read data from an InputStream:

```
private byte[] forceRead(InputStream inputStream, byte[] result)
        throws IOException {

    int bytesRead = 0;
    int total = result.length;
    int remaining = total;

    while (remaining > 0)
        remaining -= inputStream.read(result, bytesRead, remaining);

    return result;

}
```

The method used to convert a byte array to an integer:

```
private int byteArrayToInt(byte[] byteArray) {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; (i<byteArray.length) && (i<8); i++) {
        result |= (byteArray[3-i] & 0xff) << (i << 3);
    }
    return result;                  
}
```

The problem is, that the data is not read in the order it arrives. The first 4 bytes are being read just fine. The rest is mixed up. I made a TCP dump to ensure the data correctly arrives at the client. It seems as if the data is split up into 4 TCP packets. The InputStream returns the first 4 bytes of the first packet, then the entire data of the fourth packet, the last part (starting from "length of last packet") of the second packet and the entire data of the third packet. In this order.

Does anyone have a clue what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic for reading the byte array is not quite right:

From to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

> Reads up to len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of
>   bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller
>   number may be read. The number of bytes actually read is returned as
>   an integer.

and

> The first byte read is stored into element b[off], the next one into
>   b[off+1], and so on. The number of bytes read is, at most, equal to
>   len. Let k be the number of bytes actually read; these bytes will be
>   stored in elements b[off] through b[off+k-1], leaving elements
>   b[off+k] through b[off+len-1] unaffected.

However, as your `bytesRead` variable stays at 0 for the whole loop, any data from the inputstream is always written to the beginning of your buffer, overwriting the data already in there.

What will work better (checking for -1 will also ensure that you don't subtract -1 from remaining if the stream runs out of data prematurely which would result in `remaining` increase, which would mean the loop would run unnecessarily until a buffer overrun would make `remaining` negative):

```
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(result, total - remaining, remaining)) != -1
     && remaining > 0) {
    remaining -= bytesRead;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You just made my day (actually the whole next week, too) :)

Comment: Last snippet of code is very useful. It's easy to forget checking that return value.  This is an easy 2 line solution.